# Why $F(z) = |z|^2$ is holomorphic nowhere?

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives, complex-numbers

I am self-studying basic complex analysis, and am slightly confused as to how to show that $F(z) = |z|^2$ is holomorphic nowhere. A necessary and sufficient condition for the holomorphism of $F(z)$ is that $F(z)$ is independent of $\overline{z}$. That is, we require:

$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial \overline{z}}=0$$

We note that we have $F(z) = |z|^{2} = z\overline{z}$, and so we have:

$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial \overline{z}}=z$$

And so we clearly have that $F(z)$ is holomorphic everywhere, except $z = 0$, however, I don't understand why we cannot say $F(z)$ is holomorphic at $z=0$, is it because in the neighborhood of $z = 0$ we have that $F(z)$ is nowhere holomorphic?

Comment: The function is constant on each circle centered at $z=0$.  But a holomorphic function is never constant on a curve like that, unless it is constant everywhere.

Comment: Why you don't use Cauchey-Riemann conditions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're fundamentally misunderstanding the condition $\frac{\partial F}{\partial \bar{z}} = 0$. *After* you differentiate with respect to $\bar{z}$, your resultant must be zero for the function to be *complex differentiable* at that point.

Your work shows that for $F(z) = |z|^2$, $\frac{\partial F}{\partial \bar{z}} = 0$ if and only if $z = 0$. (I'm not exactly sure how you came up with the statement about it being holomorphic everywhere but zero from this condition.) Hence $F$ is complex differentiable at $0$. However for a function to be holomorphic, it must be complex differentiable *on an open set*. Holomorphicity is a much stronger condition than just complex differentiability.

Comment: You are right, I had fundamentally misunderstood the holomorphicity condition and assumed it was equivalent to complex differentiation! Thank you very much for clearing that up!

Comment: @Shaktal: It might be useful to know that the phrase "holomorphic at the point $z_0$" is sometimes used, and that this is actually an abbreviation for "holomorphic in some open *neighbourhood* of the point $z_0$".

Answer (score 0):

Because $F(z)\in\mathbb R$ for all $z\in\mathbb C$, and the only holomorphic function $f$ such that $f(z)\in\mathbb R$ for all $z$ are the constant function.